# почему мало статей в Статистике Mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

https://lorwiki.org.ru/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F:%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0

Вот там две статьи показываются, хотя в основном пространстве их больше https://lorwiki.org.ru/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F:%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B

отчего это и как исправить?
mediawiki из git

Answer (score 2):

Что бы страница распознавалась как статья, необходимо разместить ссылку. Внешнюю или внутреннюю.